# Wireless Hot Spot - how to limit accessible websites?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I'd like to allow users to use my phone as a hot spot. However, when they connect to it, I want them to only be able to use it for web browsing (e.g. not for Skype, etc.) and it should only be able to browse a website I specify. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Also mention your device and Android version in the question